# How can I declare a custom sort function on std::map declaration?

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary

The container `std::map` always sorts keys based on their value. Is it possible to make it sort, for example, on the number of bits set upon declaration?

I have a function for counting set bits:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT * sizeof value; ++i, value >>= 1) {
  if ((value & 1) == byteState) ++num_bits;
}
```

But I do not know how to apply it when declaring the map:

```
std::map<int, int> myMap = {
  {1,2},
  {3,4},
  //...
}
```

I've tried to put it as a third parameter in the declaration `<int,int,decltype(countSetBits)>`, but with no luck.

Comment: If it's a normal function you also have to pass it to the constructor as a function pointer.

Comment: Btw, gcc has a nice set of [builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), one of which `int __builtin_popcount(unsigned int)` returns the number of bits set in an integer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to wrap your function in a binary operator, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int cntBits(int value) {
    int num_bits=0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 32 ; ++i, value >>= 1) {
        if ((value & 1) == 1) ++num_bits;
    }
    return num_bits;
}

struct cntBitsCmp {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) {
        return cntBits(a) < cntBits(b);
    }
};
```

Now you can use `cntBitsCmp` in a declaration:

```
std::map<int,int,cntBitsCmp> myMap= {
    {128,2},
    {3,4},
    ...
};
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/0FwGdK). It correctly orders 128 ahead of 3, because 3 has two bits set, while 128 has only one.

Comment: You're assuming 32-bit ints.  `while (i) {++n; i&=i-1;}`

Comment: @jthill Correct. I copy-pasted the OP's code, and modified it to remove constants. I posted the code as an example, with the understanding that nobody would use this code without modifications.

Answer (score 5):

Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can also use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining a comparison function. If you combine this with [std::bitset::count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/count) instead of using your own counting function, then the code becomes rather short:

```
auto comp = [](int a, int b) { return std::bitset<32>(a).count() < std::bitset<32>(b).count(); };
std::map<int, int, decltype(comp)> m(comp);
```

Note: Similar to the [solution by Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15588509/2675154), I'm assuming 32-bit integers for the sake of clarity. Please adapt the code to your needs.

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/kecYcS)

Answer (score 1):

Basically this could work as you want:

```
bool comp(int x , int y ){
    return  __builtin_popcount(x) <  __builtin_popcount(y);
}
int main(){
    bool(*fn_pt)(int,int) = comp;
    std::map<int, int, bool(*)(int,int) > myMap (fn_pt);
    myMap[7]=11;
    myMap[8]=12;
    cout<<myMap.begin()->first<<endl;  // you get 8 instead of 7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I wrapped my function in a binary operator and used it sort my map via the length of the strings (key) all was well and it worked. However, what I did not realise is that it affected the maps find() function. Instead of finding the key that is equal to the string it would instead find the key that has the same string length as the key!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).